# aspx problems while switch webhost

Tags: asp.net

my friend have a site whole written in aspx (i dont know much about it).

we are trying to switch his web-hoster. we opened a new account (in a web-host site that supports everything we need) and moved all the files **AS IS** to the new web hoster.

now we get a:

**Directory Listing Denied**

**This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.**

what where we doing wrong? is there anything we need to concider besides putting the files in the new web-hoster...?
thanks.

Comment: Do you have a default page set up in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://yourwebsite.com/yourwebpage.aspx if this works then your deployment is correct. Now what you want is set the default page to "yourwebpage.aspx" as already commented by Brandon. Different host service provide different ways to do this. First let us know if http://yourwebsite.com/yourwebpage.aspx works. Also provide your host service provider name will look into their documentation and tell how to setup default page

Comment: hmmm it doesent work. and when i try to put a normal index/default.html it doese. i think the webhost doesent support aspx :/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the website could have been  running a url rewrite module which would require the server to pass all requests via asp.net using wildmapping.
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true

There are different ways this is handled depending on the version of IIS you are using. There is also limitations on this depending on your hosting environment.

A couple of questions that might help identity the issue

1. Was the previous hosting environment shared or dedicated/virtual
2. Was the previous hosting environment Windows 2003/IIS 6 or windows 2008/IIS 7
3. Is the new hosting environment shared or dedicated/virtual
4. Is the new hosting environment Windows 2003/IIS 6 or windows 2008/IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

Before and application can run, you need to specify that the folder is  an asp.net application. There should be a way to do this through your control panel, if not contact the vendor